# How can I write each dataframe in a list to an existing csv with the same name in R using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of data frames. Each dataframe has a name. I want to write each report inside the list and append them on existing csv reports with the same name.

I tried a for loop but I am unable to pull the name so that I can append to the correct csv.

```
report_list <- c(report1, report2, report3) #for simplicity I'm just listing the reports but these are actually df that were imported from a directory

for (report in report_list) {
  write.table(report, 
              file = paste(report,".csv", sep = ""), # I was expecting this would extract the name of the specific df in the current loop but not.
              append = TRUE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Map` or `purrr::map2`:

```r
Map(function(report, nm) {
  write.table(report, 
              file = paste(nm, ".csv", sep = ""),
              append = TRUE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",")
}, report_list, names(report_list))
```

or

```
purrr::imap(report_list,
  ~ write.table(.x, 
              file = paste(.y,".csv", sep = ""),
              append = TRUE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",")
)
```

or iterate your `for` loop over the *names* instead:

```r
for (nm in names(report_list)) {
  report <- report_list[[nm]]
  write.table(report, 
              file = paste(nm,".csv", sep = ""),
              append = TRUE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",")
}
``
```

Comment: Will report_list have names?

Comment: Ummm ... good point @IRTFM, I made a leap that it was really a named-list underneath ... perhaps the OP will come back with more problems since `c(...)` is unlikely to be the best way to do that ...